# How to calculate average within column on csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, average

I'm trying to calculate the average for a set of numbers within a column in a csv file. I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range. but I know the number is within the range so idk what im doing wrong. if I change it to print row[0], it prints out "e
a
r
t
h
q
u
a
k
e
s
.
c
s
v" which is the name of the file so that's definitely not right.

def average_magnitude(file_name):
file = open("earthquakes.csv","r")
file.readline()

```
for each_line in file_name:
    each_line = each_line.strip()
    row = each_line.split(",")
    print(row[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have it taking "each_line" from file_name, and not from the file variable.